# Piwik - Average load times for mobile devices?

Tags: reporting, matomo

Is there a way in Piwik that I can check how long certain pages are loading for mobiles, either on average or by individual site visits?

If not I would settle for a way to see average load times, if that's possible at all.

Comment: Don't think you can without using the [Server Log Import toolkit](http://piwik.org/docs/page-speed/) combined with regex to filter through user agents, looking through my setup which uses the latest version only uses an average of overall page generation time.

Comment: Although this isn't exactly what you are looking for, you can use Google's page speed insights tool to see your mobile vs. desktop scores and recommendations for improving speed. They also provide an API which you can use to ping multiple URLs. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this in Piwik is to have your mobile pages served from a dub domain in which case you will be able to track the average load times based on the sub domain. Otherwise if you have specific page URL's for mobile pages you can check the breakdown of page load times by page at `Actions > Pages and Actions > Page Titles`.

http://piwik.org/docs/page-speed/